# Sending from a shared mailbox without using sentOnBehalfOf

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I'm currently using `outlook.application` to send mail from a shared mailbox.

I need a way to send these messages without my email address appearing on the 'from' list. It should only be the shared mailbox appearing. At the moment i'm using `.sentOnBehalfOf`, is there something else i should be using?

Answer (score 2):

Request Send As permission.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7fd3e945-092a-461b-afa9-a126b8cc3cdd/configure-outlook-to-send-as-permissions

You should be able choose the shared account in the From field of email.

Use .SendUsingAccount to specify the shared account in VBA.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/account.htm

```
Sub Which_Account_Number()
'Don't forget to set a reference to Outlook in the VBA editor
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim I As Long

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For I = 1 To OutApp.Session.Accounts.Count
    MsgBox OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(I) & " : This is account number " & I
Next I
End Sub
```

The shared account will likely be 2.

```
With OutMail

    .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)

End With
```